# Realizar una acción cuando la condición del operador filter no se cumpla

Tags: angular, typescript, filtro, rxjs, pipe

Buen día a tod@s. Estoy realizando una petición que me retorna la información de esta manera:

```
{
  result:0,
  message:"Mensaje",
  data:{}
}
```

Tengo el servicio con un método donde realizo un post

```
peticionProceso(data: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.url_api, data);
}
```

En el componente me suscribo a ese método y hago uso de los operadores pipe, map y filter. El inconveniente sucede en el filter que no comprendo si hay alguna manera de ejecutar una segunda función si la condición del "result" no es igual a 1.

```
ejecutarProceso(info:any) {
    return this.servicio.peticionProceso(info)
        .pipe(
            filter(x => x.result == 1),
            map(
                x => this.onFuncion1(x.data)
            )).subscribe();
}
```

No quisiera hacer lo siguiente:

```
ejecutarProceso(info:any) {
    return this.servicio.peticionProceso(info)
        .subscribe(
          res=>{
             if(res.result==1){
               this.onFuncion1(res.data)
             }else{
               //función 2
             }
         })
}
```

Comment: Estas buscando hacerlo con operadores rxjs o alguna razón particular por la que el if no es una opción?

Comment: @JhonRM Estuve investigando y si lo hago de la segunda forma sería una mala práctica ya que vendría a ser una manera "anti-reactiva"

Comment: Existen los [operadores condicionales en rxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/conditional).

Comment: Y creo que te interesa el operador [`ìff`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/conditional/iif)

Answer (score 0):

Pues probar con el operador `tap`:

```
ejecutarProceso(info:any) {
    return this.servicio.peticionProceso(info)
        .pipe(
            tap(x => {
              if (x.result !== 1) {
                // TODO Llama a la otra función
              }
            }),
            filter(x => x.result == 1),
            map(
                x => this.onFuncion1(x.data)
            )).subscribe();
}
```